# Problems with emacs syntax highlighting for python programs

Tags: python, emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

I am using `python-mode` for syntax highlighting. Everything is fine *except* the highlighting of docstrings, which makes reading code in github repositories with complex docstrings very difficult to do. Here an example:

```
class DoubleQuotesDocString:
    """
    This is a doc string but inside double quotes " the highlinting breaks: in for type while " so this is a bug
    """

class SingleQuotesDocString:
    '''
    This is a doc string but inside single quotes ' the highlinting breaks: in for type while ' so this is a bug
'''
```

And the corresponding screenshot where you see that it is not properly highlighted:

[image: bad-highlighting]

Of course this is a simple example. A complex docstring full of such highlighting bugs is completely unreadable.

Is there a solution for this?

EDIT: funny, stackoverflow highlighting also has trouble with this.

Comment: In my default emacs python-mode it works fine. I'm not an emacs pro but you can always try checking the python mode settings on Py → PyTools → Customize python mode.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but it is not related to the settings. I have just found out that I am using a very old version of python-mode.el (5.1.0). The current version (6.1.1) does not have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to swtich from `python-mode.el` version 5.1.0 to version 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to affect the default python-mode that comes bundled with Emacs.

Comment: Sorry for necrobumping but looks like things changed over time. Emacs 27.0.50 is affected by this issue.

Comment: And now it's [fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=5feaf906e110097a443af78f549f01c1bd527e25). Thank you.